# js - 'this' is undefined when calling method 'indirectly'

Tags: javascript, rhino

My goal is to call a function from a table of functions to generalize command handling (i.e indirectly). Unfortunately, `this` is`undefined` when called as such.

```
function Server() {
    this.sessions = {};

    server = this;
    this.handlers = {
        "dummy" : server.dummyCommandHandler,
    };
}

Server.prototype.dummyCommandHandler = function() {
    print (this.sessions);
}

Server.prototype.run = function ( command ) {
    print (this.sessions); // [Object object]
    this.handlers[command.name](); // prints 'undefined'
    this.dummyCommandHandler(); // prints '[Object object]'
}

s = new Server();
s.run({ "name": "dummy" });
```

This is my first time using javascript, and I thought I had the scoping down but apparently it is more complicated than it seems. Aliasing Server's `this` with the `server` variable didn't help (I thought perhaps `this` changes hands within the `handlers` object). What is the scope of `this` when the function is called indirectly?

Comment: First problem I can see ~ `server = this` bad, `var server = this` good

Comment: `this.handlers[command.name].bind(this)();`

Comment: What's your testing environment? I copied and pasted this into the console in my browser and it seemed to work as expected?

Comment: @Phil ah thanks to Python for that one...doesn't affect this issue though

Comment: @hlfrmn or in the constructor ~ `dummy: this.dummyCommandHandler.bind(this)`

Comment: @JohnHenry I am using Rhino JS

Comment: @hlfrmn 'Cannot find function bind'. This doesn't seem to be supported by Rhino, but they may have something similar. I'd have to do some research

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default behavior for `this` is that <strike>it refers to the function scope at the time it's invoked</strike> (see below). You can force the value of `this` by either using `bind` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)) or using arrow function syntax, which lexically-scopes your references to `this` to wherever you defined the function. This is the change I would make:

`"dummy" : server.dummyCommandHandler.bind(this),`

Comment: "*this…refers to the function scope at the time it's invoked*" is incorrect. A function's *this* has nothing to do with scope, it's set by the call or use of *bind* (or lexically for arrow functions, but they're not part of the OP). See [*MDN: this*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: @BihnKim 'Cannot find function bind'. This doesn't seem to be supported by Rhino JS, unfortunately

Comment: @MzyBwy—there is a [*polyfill at MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Polyfill).

Comment: Also, I don't think you need the "server" variable anymore. Should just be able to do:

```"dummy" : this.dummyCommandHandler.bind(this),
```