# Property of this is undefined when used as Middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Container `class`:

```
// container.js
function Container(clients) {
    this.clients = clients;
}

Container.prototype.test = function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(this.clients['key']);
    next();
};

module.exports = Container;
```

And then from another file I create an express server:

```
// server.js
const Express = require('express');
const BodyParser = require('body-parser');
const Container = require('./container');

var box = new Container({'key': 'secret' });

var app = new Express();
app.use(BodyParser.json());
app.use(box.test);

// some routes...

app.listen(3000);
```

When I make requests I get this logged to the console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined
```

I'm so confused. I've [read up on many different things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42286809/js-this-is-undefined-when-calling-method-indirectly) about the improper use of `this` but I can't see where I'm messing this up?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get a function from the object `app.use(box.test)`, it loses it's context and `this` doesn't refer to the `object` itself. You need to use the `bind()` function to create a function with attached context, or just use `arrow function` and inside it call your function on the object.

```
app.use(() => box.test());
```

With `bind`

```
app.use(box.test.bind(box));
```

Comment: Superb! How would one do it with `bind()`?

Comment: @ShawnThroop Edited